# ag-grid: tool panel layout breaks when column name is long

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

The tool panel in ag-grid breaks in an unsightly manner when a column name is goes past a certain length. The tool panel checkbox options below it end up looking bad. Is there a work-around for this issue?

Here is a plunkr demonstrating the issue:
https://plnkr.co/edit/r1FyN8hZILiuocXTX2Bw?p=preview

```
    ...
    headerName: 'Game Name Is Too Long',
    field: 'game.name',
    width: 267,
    ...
```

[image]

Comment: i am seeing it displayed fine for me. which browser are you using?

Comment: @Niladri - The tool panel is not on by default, but I updated the plunkr to change that setting, so if you open the page now, you should see the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like CSS bug. This is not right place to report bugs. You should report this issue to ag-grid. As workaround, just add to your css (after ag-grid styles) something like:

```
.ag-column-select-label {
    max-width: 140px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: This is what we have been doing in our app.